# Cross-correlation Code in C#

Tags: c#, statistics, correlation

HI all, I have been hunting around for some code that implements various correlation coefficients (specifically cross-correlation) in C# to no avail. The one I found [alglib](http://www.alglib.net/) has some licensing requirements, surely there must some F/OSS implementation for such a common statistical function.

Comment: Why in the world was this closed as too narrow?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Meta.Numerics](http://www.meta-numerics.net) library supports the computation of correla