# How to make MATLAB's corrcoef (correlation coefficient) in C#?

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a List with many samples representing many Amplitude values from a noisy sinusoidal wave. 
I need to find the Pearson's correlation coefficient for this wave and a given sinusoidal wave (not noisy). (So I can find the right harmonic from my noisy wave).
What I really need is to do the same procedure in a method in C#.
I know that this can be done with corrcoef command in MATLAB.
Any explanation or idea is very welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correlation of two arrays in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17447817/2433501).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/)

> Math.NET Numerics aims to provide methods and algorithms for numerical
>   computations in science, engineering and every day use. Covered topics
>   include special functions, linear algebra, probability models, random
>   numbers, interpolation, integration, regression, optimization problems
>   and more.

the [class](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Statistics/Correlation.htm) You are looking for is coded like:

```
namespace MathNet.Numerics.Statistics
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Properties;

    /// <summary>
    /// A class with correlation measures between two datasets.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Correlation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Computes the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataA">Sample data A.</param>
        /// <param name="dataB">Sample data B.</param>
        /// <returns>The Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient.</returns>
        public static double Pearson(IEnumerable<double> dataA, IEnumerable<double> dataB)
        {
            int n = 0;
            double r = 0.0;
            double meanA = dataA.Mean();
            double meanB = dataB.Mean();
            double sdevA = dataA.StandardDeviation();
            double sdevB = dataB.StandardDeviation();

            IEnumerator<double> ieA = dataA.GetEnumerator();
            IEnumerator<double> ieB = dataB.GetEnumerator();

            while (ieA.MoveNext())
            {
                if (ieB.MoveNext() == false)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Datasets dataA and dataB need to have the same length.");
                }

                n++;
                r += (ieA.Current - meanA) * (ieB.Current - meanB) / (sdevA * sdevB);
            }
            if (ieB.MoveNext() == true)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Datasets dataA and dataB need to have the same length.");
            }

            return r / (n - 1);
        }
    }
}


Math.NET Numerics works very well with C# and related .Net languages. When using Visual Studio or another IDE with built-in NuGet support, you can get started quickly by adding a reference to the MathNet.Numerics NuGet package. Alternatively you can grab that package with the command line tool with nuget.exe install MathNet.Numerics -Pre or simply download the Zip package.
```

I have used this library intensively with good results. So you would use it like:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.Statistics;

correlation = Correlation.Pearson(arrayOfDoubles1, arrayOfDoubles2);
```

Comment: It seems it does the hard work for me, I was seeking to do it myself, but it'll  be ok, now I just have to thresh it myself. Thank you very much sir.