# Find and determine similarity between two datasets with delay and variation

Tags: algorithm, correlation, similarity, cross-correlation

I have multiple, fixed, identical sensors, each monitoring a different room, throughout a day. The sensors produce data as pairs: integer value and timestamp. The sensors capture data at varying time intervals (based on the local condition variations) producing on average 10000 samples per day.

Another sensor (connected to a mobile unit, sensor similar to the fixed ones above) is used to capture data all day and it sometimes enters a room that has a fixed sensor, but I do now know which room. A mobile sensor can visit multiple rooms. Therefore we have data for the mobile unit in the rooms with sensors and in other areas with no sensors.

Considerations:
- I have a pretty good timestamp on the mobile sensor data (max. a few seconds – introduced by the clock sync really); 
- While in a room, the mobile sensor will give similar but not identical results with the fixed sensor placed in the room. 
-The mobile sensor data is collected / downloaded to be analyzed at the end of the day.

**The question: What is the best way to proceed in determining the rooms where the mobile sensor has entered?  I am looking for an algorithm not a specific implementation, but if you have any, C# would be nice.**

**My idea**: I have split the mobile sensor data in small chunks (about 5 minutes that I have determined to be the minimum time range to distinguish between data sets) then, for each chunk I have used a correlation function to compute the correlation coefficient (as seen here: [Correlation of two arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447817/correlation-of-two-arrays-in-c-sharp)) between the mobile and the fixed sensor data at that time position (I run +/- a few seconds and get the best value to handle the possible lag). This works but I was wondering if there is another (better way) to proceed?

**@moderators** I am not entirely sure that this is entirely a programming question, please feel free to move it to the correct forum if necessary. Thanks!