# How to tell if two FFT results are similar?

Tags: c#, fft, correlation

After doing two FFTs, how can you tell how similar the results are? 
For example, lets take a look at these FFT results:

[image]

- Blue (left top corner) shows the ideal signal.
- Green (right top corner) shows a signal that should be detected as similar.
- Red (left bottom corner) shows a signal that should be detected as different.

I'm looking for a function, that takes two arrays with fft results and returns a number between 0.0 and 1.0, depending on how similar the two arrays of input values are. Is there something like this already available in a C# library?
If not, how would you calculate this? What's the math behind it?

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correlation of two arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447817/correlation-of-two-arrays-in-c-sharp) , or this one: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54970/comparing-multiple-signals-for-similarity

Comment: @Renat, yes it does. Thank you very much!