# Is there a way to attribute double array elements to string array elements?

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to make a program that shows a number from a double type array next to its corresponding element from a string type array.

Basically I have:

```
double[] number = new double[3]
number[0] = 1.1;
number[1] = 7.8;
number[2] = 6.0;

string[] text = new string[3]
text[0] = "Text1";
text[1] = "Text2";
text[2] = "Text3";
```

And I need some way to write something like text[1] - number[1]

Comment: Something like: `Console.WriteLine($"{text[1]} - {number[1]}");`? If not, I'm not quite sure what you're asking...

Comment: `Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, text.Zip(number, (t, n) => $"{t} - {n}")));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correlation of two arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447817/correlation-of-two-arrays-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using each array's enumerator

```
var numberEnumerator = number.GetEnumerator();
var textEnumerator = text.GetEnumerator();
while (numberEnumerator.MoveNext() && textEnumerator.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine($"{textEnumerator.Current} - {numberEnumerator.Current}");
```

This is the basics. You can get fancier by using extension methods, generics, or pulling in a NuGet package such as MoreLinq, which has a [Zip()](https://morelinq.github.io/1.x/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Zip__3.htm) method to combine sequences element by element.

Comment: Zip is built in with LINQ, no need for an added package.

Comment: True. It wasn't always so... two open source's doing good things: adding useful methods!

Comment: Right. It's been around since framework 4.0 only... So not since linq but definitely quite some time :-p